# Pass youtube iframe api events onstatechange when src changes

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

So I figured I would update this with a working example.  I have ditched stating the iframe tag and just used the iframe api to create an iframe and then loaded the player by id with a data attribute.  Here is a working example below.  So now all statechanges are passed consistently through the youtube player.  So the script will load an iframe into the Div #player and you can just loadVideoByID pretty easily with jquery and javascript.

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0,},
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    alert('started');
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
     if(event.data === 0) {            
         alert('done');
     }
}
$( document ).on( "click", ".video-link", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
    player.loadVideoById(videoID);
});
</script>
```

And then use a link with a data-attribute like so.

```
<a href="#" class="video-link"  data-videoID="youtube id here">Link</a>
```

Comment: How are you changing the player src? If you want the player to play a new video I would recommend using `player.loadVideoById('NewVideoID')` All the events for the player should work just fine. If you want to console log the new video ID to see the change in the console "debugging/reporting" try this `console.log(player.getVideoUrl().split('?v=')[1]);`

Comment: I was just using a traditional link like in the fiddle and targeting the iframe link <a href="youtubelink" target="iframe"></a> I will look into using javascript to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having buttons to play, why not cue to playlist when the player is ready? You can hold the video ID's in an array... If this isn't what you're looking for just leave a comment below and I will change things the best I can to fit.

```
//Array of videos
var MyVideos=["E6RGMRamAFk","IHQr0HCIN2w","CogIXrea6A4"];
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
     'onReady': onPlayerReady,
     'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
//Player is ready, cue the array of videos into the playlist.
player.cuePlaylist(MyVideos);
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
}
```

[JS Fiddle - Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zpg2c9ts/9/)

> **[YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en)**

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this help. Happy coding!

Comment: I would but i am going to have people add to the playlist so I wanted to have the playlist clickable in case they wanted to watch a video out of order from normal so I am looking into the player.loadVideoById right now and just attach a click event to each link.  Im still not quite sure how I want to go about this thanks

Comment: @user3331344 You can create a function to add new videos into the array, the player comes with a side menu to select videos from the playlist (top left of the player). Your question is how to create a playlist, if you want to add more to the playlist you can cue more videos into the player. I will add a link in the answer to the API Reference, everything is in there.