# Multiple embedded youtube videos on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

Is it possible,  Don't play multiple video at a time

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcMkt/823/)

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video1"></iframe>

<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video2"></iframe>

<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video3"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem/question. Do you mean: How can you pause/stop a video if one is playing while when/if the client selects  another/new video to play?

Comment: yes,  video play/pause  @NewToJS

Comment: I recommend you look at using youtubes player API. https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en This will give you more control over the player events. You can also create your own playlist. Example of the playlist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001845/pass-youtube-iframe-api-events-onstatechange-when-src-changes/32002478#32002478

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Youtube API for controlling videos by using javascript: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en

Comment: Well, creating "javascript objects" for all your videos using the API gives you more control and you can use "event handlers" to do what you want.