# How do you make 2 YouTube videos automatically play one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, youtube

I'm trying to figure out how to make 2 videos automatically play one after the other, i.e. as soon as the first video finishes, the second video starts. How can this be done? http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/8hc3mf27/

HTML

```
<div class="videowrapper">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zgQaEAhMIOI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="videowrapper">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zgQaEAhMIOI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.videosetter{

}
.videowrapper {
    /*float: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;*/
}
.videowrapper iframe {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 12px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    margin-left:0px; 
    width:250px;
    height:145px;   
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    this.player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: pxHeight,
        width: pxWidth,
        playerVars: {
            'rel': 0,
            'controls': 0,
            'fs':0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onError': onError
        }
    });

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            LOG("Youtube Playing");
        } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            LOG(">>>Youtube Ended");
            this.player.loadVideoById(ID, 0, "default");
        } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            LOG("Youtube Paused");
        } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
            LOG("Youtube Buffering");
        } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
            LOG("Youtube Cued");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: You haven't put all the elements on the fiddle. What is `this` here, `pxHeight` and `pxWidth` ! You missed the call to the API to

Comment: I recommend you go back to https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en and add the missing parts of the API. Also, where is the element with `player` id? You don't need to create two iframes, the API will do everything for you once you have it set up. It sounds like you want to create a playlist. You might find this answer useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001845/pass-youtube-iframe-api-events-onstatechange-when-src-changes/32002478#32002478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10nrzpdn/) that I made to play second video as soon as first video finishes.

```
var player1, player2;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
      height: '195',
      width: '320',
      videoId: 'zgQaEAhMIOI',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayer1Ready,    //Called first
        'onStateChange': onPlayer1StateChange //Called when #player1 state changes
      }
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
      height: '195',
      width: '320',
      videoId: 'zgQaEAhMIOI',
      events: {
        'onReady': null,        //Set to null as it is controlled by #player1 
        'onStateChange': null   //Set to null as it is controlled by #player1 
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayer1Ready(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  function onPlayer1StateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) { //When #player1 video ends,
      player2.playVideo();                    //#player2 video starts
    }
  }
```

It is based completely on [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: Is it that you necessarily have to create a Player for each? Can't you re-assign the first one after it finishes?

Comment: @gfcf14 given OP's code example, I assumed that he requires 2 separate players.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've been googling, and in case OP ever needs it, you can use `player.loadVideoById` to load on the same one